# Rails Application causes javascript to break

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, video.js, brightcove

I'm loading a couple of javascript files then calling a function. It works fine on my local but as soon as I put it into my rails app I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: videojs.getPlayer is not a function.

Full error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: videojs.getPlayer is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):254)
at fire (jquery.self-.js?body=1:3233)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.self-.js?body=1:3363)
at Function.ready (jquery.self-.js?body=1:3583)
at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.self-.js?body=1:3618)
```

I have tried adding it to a local / static html file which works fine. It makes me believe it has something to do either turbo links or jquery, which I also have installed.

```
<div>
<video-js id="myPlayerID"
data-video-id="5582672913001"
data-account="4946658880001"
data-player="9GbrNQqvn"
data-embed="default"
class="video-js" controls></video>
</div>
<script src="https://players.brightcove.net/4946658880001/9GbrNQqvn_default/index.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>video start cookie value = <span id="cookieDisplay1"></span></p>
<p>current cookie value = <span id="cookieDisplay2"></span></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/thypowerhouse/raw/upload/v1547938129/fishflicks_brightcove/plugin-dev.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {"overlayText": "SKIP IT", "cue_point": 15};
</script>
<script>videojs.getPlayer('myPlayerID').pluginDev(options);</script>
```

The video player that loads SHOULD display a skip intro link and the video start cookie value should be set to 0

Answer (score 0):

The reuqest to get the videojs library is asynchronous. You'll probably need to add a check to see if the library is already loaded or load it manually inside the javascript with a promise/callback to call your function once it's done